# How to create javascript or css fadeInDown on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The idea of what I want to create is: I have some div as trigger when I mouse over on these div than their data will show in a specific div (the right side bordered div), and when I mouse out than the default data will show, and each time there will be a fadeInDown effect. Here is I have done as far

```html
<style type="text/css">
.content {
   margin-left: 200px;
   border: 1px solid;
   height : 0;
   opacity : 0;
   transition : opacity .3s ease, height .3s ease;
   -webkit-transition : opacity .3s ease, height .3s ease;
   -moz-transition : opacity .3s ease, height .3s ease;
   position: absolute;
}
.content.fade-in-down {
   opacity : 1;
   height : 100px;
}
.trigger {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background-color: #333;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}
</style>
<script>
  function show(id) {
        document.getElementById("default").classList.remove("fade-in-down");
        setTimeout(function(){ 
         var el = document.getElementById(id);
             el.classList.add("fade-in-down");
      }, 500);
  }
  function hide(id) {
        var el = document.getElementById(id);
            el.classList.remove("fade-in-down");
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            document.getElementById("default").classList.add("fade-in-down");
        }, 500);
  }

  window.onload = function(e) {
    var el = document.getElementById("default");
    el.classList.add("fade-in-down");
  };
</script>

<div style="display: block; width: 100%">
    <!--These Three div are the trigger-->
    <div style="float: left;">
        <div onMouseOver="show('div1');" onMouseOut="hide('div1')" class="trigger"></div>
        <div onMouseOver="show('div2');" onMouseOut="hide('div2')" class="trigger"></div>
        <div onMouseOver="show('div3');" onMouseOut="hide('div3')" class="trigger"></div>
    </div>
    <!--These are the data-->
    <div id="default" class="content" style="position: absolute;">This is default</div>
    <div id="div1" class="content">Div 1 Content</div>
    <div id="div2" class="content">Div 2 Content</div>
    <div id="div3" class="content">Div 3 Content</div>
</div>
```

Now the problem is: in the bordered div when I mouse over on div1, div2 or div3 the data is showing but the previous div data are also showing and it looks messy. and i used slide down it will be better if I can use fadeInDown effect instead of slide down with fade

Comment: Do you want a purely javascript solution i.e. no jquery at all?

Comment: if its work than it will be okay for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated your example to include a `ClearSelection` method, which is called whenever the `show` or `hide` methods are triggered.

The html has been changed to include a wrapping `div` with an `id` of "data". This is so that the child nodes can be queried when the `ClearSelection` method is called.

The `ClearSelection` method loops through all of the children within the "data" `div` and removes the "fade-in-down" class, ensuring that only a single `div` is visible at any one time.

```css
.content {
  margin-left: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s ease, height .3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease, height .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease, height .3s ease;
  position: absolute;
}
.content.fade-in-down {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 100px;
}
.trigger {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: block; width: 100%">
  <!--These Three div are the trigger-->
  <div style="float: left;">
    <div onMouseOver="show('div1');" onMouseOut="hide('div1')" class="trigger"></div>
    <div onMouseOver="show('div2');" onMouseOut="hide('div2')" class="trigger"></div>
    <div onMouseOver="show('div3');" onMouseOut="hide('div3')" class="trigger"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="data">
    <!--These are the data-->
    <div id="default" class="content" style="position: absolute;">This is default</div>
    <div id="div1" class="content">Div 1 Content</div>
    <div id="div2" class="content">Div 2 Content</div>
    <div id="div3" class="content">Div 3 Content</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  function show(id) {
    document.getElementById("default").classList.remove("fade-in-down");
    setTimeout(function() {
      //Clear any prior selections.
      ClearSelection();
      var el = document.getElementById(id);
      el.classList.add("fade-in-down");
      var defaultEl = document.getElementById("default");
      //If the default element has a class of "fade-in-down", remove it.
      if (defaultEl.className.indexOf("fade-in-down") !== -1) {
        defaultEl.classList.remove("fade-in-down");
      }
    }, 500);
  }

  function hide(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    el.classList.remove("fade-in-down");
    setTimeout(function() {
      //Clear any prior selections
      ClearSelection();
      //Find the default element.
      var defaultEl = document.getElementById("default");
      //If the default element doesn't have a class of "fade-in-down", add it.
      if (defaultEl.className.indexOf("fade-in-down") === -1) {
        defaultEl.classList.add("fade-in-down");
      }
    }, 500);
  }

  function ClearSelection() {
    var parent = document.getElementById('data');
    if (parent != null && parent.children.length > 0) {
      //Loop through all of the child nodes and remove the "fade-in-down" class.
      for (var i = 0; i < parent.children.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById(parent.children[i].id).classList.remove("fade-in-down");
      }
    }
  }

  window.onload = function(e) {
    var el = document.getElementById("default");
    el.classList.add("fade-in-down");
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Can I ask another favor?

Comment: It depends, what's up?

Comment: Is it possible to use fade in down effect instead of slide?